# How to extract excel attachement from file correctly

Tags: apache-nifi

am trying to read email box and extract attached excel file, I used `ExtractEmailAttachements` for that but it's generate a flow file with the below content instead of the attached file

```
------=_Part_186_1669651663.1615384872702
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */

    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" /></xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:shapelayout v:ext="edit"><o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" /></o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang="EN-US" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72" style="word-wrap:break-word"><div class="WordSection1"><p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p></div></body></html>
------=_Part_186_1669651663.1615384872702
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; 
    name="5K.xlsx"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename="5K.xlsx"
Content-Description: 

UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBi7p1oXgEAAJAEAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAAC
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

the flow looks like this

[image]

Comment: what do you have before ExtractEmailAttachments in flowfile content?

Comment: @daggett I have  `consumeEWS`--> `ExtractEmailHeaders`--> `RouteOnAttribute`-->`ExtractEmailAttachment`

Comment: @Exorcismus - he is asking for content of the flowfile. Also refer to this sample article - https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-read-an-email-using-Apache-Nifi-and-extract/td-p/181251

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde this already was the link am following to apply my flow

Comment: @exorcismus, please edit question and provide the sample flow file after consumeEws.